# How is this phrase translated?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

Alright, I am not sure if the phrase itself is enough to make a good German translation. That is why [here](https://www.lyricsfreak.com/m/motionless+in+white/holding+on+to+smoke_1646409.html) are the full lyrics.

The part of the lyrics I want to translate is:

> I just fuck it up as you lap it up

A bit more context for the line:

> If I give will you take
>   As I lie for the taste
>   I just fuck it up
>   And you lap it up

I found a few translations, which for me don't make any sense in the context of the lyrics. For example

> Ich scheiß drauf, wie du es auflegst

is how Google translates it. [musinfo.net](http://musinfo.net/lyrics/motionless-in-white/holding-on-to-smoke) translates it with

> Ich scheiß drauf Und du legst los

For my German mind, neither translation makes any sense in the context of the song. **So my question is, how would this phrase be translated to still fit into the song context?**

Comment: do you have an own proposal?

Comment: @AGuyCalledGerald Nope. The translations I can find for "to lap" don't make any sense either. What would make the most sense would be something like "Ich zerstöre es, während du es aufwischt", but the english words don't really match this

Comment: I'd rather use a more "static" link, as I have no idea if this site is "valid", I just propose a link: https://www.lyricsfreak.com/m/motionless+in+white/holding+on+to+smoke_1646409.html   ... and you could inlude "neighbour phrases" into your question to show more context.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would take the figurative meaning of "to lap up" into account, which is "etwas begierig aufnehmen", "etwas kritiklos akzeptieren". The lyrics seem to play with the tension between the figurative and the literal / "oral" meaning of the phrase. So I'd translate it as something like "Ich mach's kaputt, während Du es einfach schluckst".

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for it not to lap but **[to lap up](https://www.dict.cc/englisch-deutsch/to+lap+up.html)**.

Your translation is also not very far off then.

> "Ich zerstöre es, während du es aufwischt"

If you use to lap it up with the translation "auflecken", you get:

> Ich zerstöre es, während du/ihr es aufleck(s)t.

I would probably go for:

> Während ich es nur zerstöre, leckst du es auf.

Zerstöre is a rather mild translation but if you are ok with it I think it is fine.
The rest of the lyrics do not really give context to me but I think the translation is right.